# Formatting a column to line up with data in a text file

Tags: numpy, python-3.3

I am trying to set-up a text file so that the data is directly in line with its given header.  For instance the file contains 7 headers (t, x(t) ect...)

```
np.savetxt('vel.dat', Velocity_Col, fmt='%.5e', delimiter=('      '), header = ('     t            x(t)            y(t)            z(t)            vx(t)            vy(t)            vz(t)'))
```

The data is under each header, however they begin to trail off.

https://imgflip.com/i/dq514

First time posting sorry if i am doing this wrong, also the picture upload is not good but you can see the offset of the data.

Cheers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `5` in `'%.5e'` sets the number of digits displayed after the decimal point.  You also want to control the total width of each field.  That is controlled with a number before the decimal point in the format specification.  (The number sets the *minimum* field width.  More characters will be used if needed.)  For example, you could use `fmt='%15.5e'` to ensure that each field uses 15 characters.  You wouldn't need that long delimiter; the default delimiter would be fine.  Then adjust `header` to match.